# SQL: Attribute matches two different conditions at the same time

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to make a query where an attribute (same attribute) matches two different conditions at the same time. I have to check if a driver was found in both cities.

I tried to use intersect but I don't get any matches. But in my table I have one driver that matches this conditions.

```
SELECT s.NumeSofer 
  FROM Soferi s 
    INNER JOIN contraventii c ON s.idSofer=c.idSofer 
    INNER JOIN localitati l ON c.idLocContr=l.idLoc 
      WHERE l.DenLoc IN ('Iasi', 'Rosiori') AND l.Jud IN ('IS', 'NT');

INTERSECT

SELECT s.NumeSofer 
  FROM Soferi s 
    INNER JOIN contraventii c ON s.idSofer=c.idSofer 
    INNER JOIN localitati l ON c.idLocContr=l.idLoc 
      WHERE l.DenLoc='Rosiori' AND l.Jud='NT';
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I am training for Oracle. But atm I am using Oracle Live SQL

Comment: If you're using Live SQL (or SQL fiddle), it would be really helpful in the future to share a link to your session as part of providing a reproducible example (or feel free to copy and paste the example here).  People may be able to guess at what your tables and data look like and come up with a script for simple things but you'll get much more help if we can see what you're seeing before we answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a `GROUP BY` instead. Use `case` expressions to do conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT s.NumeSofer, count(distinct l.DenLoc) as totcount,
       count(case when l.DenLoc='Rosiori' then 1 end) as Rosioricount,
       count(case when l.DenLoc='Iasi' then 1 end) as Iasicount
FROM Soferi s
INNER JOIN contraventii c ON s.idSofer=c.idSofer
INNER JOIN localitati l ON c.idLocContr=l.idLoc
WHERE (l.DenLoc='Rosiori' AND l.Jud='NT')
   OR (l.DenLoc='Iasi' AND l.Jud='IS')
GROUP BY s.NumeSofer
ORDER BY totcount desc
```

Any rows with totcount = 2?

To get only drivers with both DenLoc's add a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT s.NumeSofer, count(distinct l.DenLoc) as totcount,
       count(case when l.DenLoc='Rosiori' then 1 end) as Rosioricount,
       count(case when l.DenLoc='Iasi' then 1 end) as Iasicount
FROM Soferi s
INNER JOIN contraventii c ON s.idSofer=c.idSofer
INNER JOIN localitati l ON c.idLocContr=l.idLoc
WHERE (l.DenLoc='Rosiori' AND l.Jud='NT')
   OR (l.DenLoc='Iasi' AND l.Jud='IS')
GROUP BY s.NumeSofer
HAVING count(distinct l.DenLoc) > 1
```

Comment: Thank you for answering me. With solution provided by you I get as result names of all the drivers even if they were finned only in 'Iasi' or only in 'Rosiori'. But i need to get only the name of the driver that was finned in both.

Comment: That's query 2, with HAVING!

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation and a `HAVING` clause, like:

```
SELECT s.NumeSofer
FROM Soferi s
INNER JOIN contraventii c ON s.idSofer=c.idSofer
INNER JOIN localitati l 
    ON c.idLocContr = l.idLoc
    AND (l.DenLoc, l.Jud) IN ( ('Iasi', 'IS'),  ('Rosiori', 'NT') )
GROUP BY s.NumeSofer
HAVING 
    MAX(CASE WHEN l.DenLoc = 'Iasi' AND l.Jud = 'IS' THEN 1 END) = 1
    AND MAX(CASE WHEN l.DenLoc = 'Rosiori' AND l.Jud = 'NT' THEN 1 END) = 1
```

This will bring you all `NumeSofer` for which at least one record exists in `localitati` with `DenLoc='Iasi' AND Jud='IS'` and at least one record exists with `DenLoc='Rosiori' AND Jud='NT'`.

Note: the `IN` operator can be used with tuple values; this reduce the lenght of the query, while avoiding using `OR`, which is usually not good for general performance.